# Overlapping two datagrids in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

In my project (WPF) I used two datagrids that two datagrids are placed one by one in same xaml window. When I run the application these two datagrids are overlapping. How can separate these two datagrids?

Comment: We all would be happy to help if you could provide us with your code

Comment: @user1681748 show us your XAML

Answer (score -1):

Well you can try something like this

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Azure"></Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="BlanchedAlmond"></Grid>

</Grid>
```

Worked for me You can define two grids in Maingrid Columns

Hope it helps